# how to simply run image with volume

Tags: docker

I using latest docker for windows beta (native).

I have a directory:

```
code.hs
Dockerfile
```

I want to create and image that will have this directory as mounted `/app` and run code there. Also I want changes I made on the host to this files (code.hs) be visible inside the container. So I do:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:7.10
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME .:/app
CMD ["ghci"]
```

When I run:

```
docker build . -t my-test
docker run -it my-test bash

> #app - inside the container is empty
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

- [declaring the VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume)
- [mounting the host-dir to that volume path](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).

That is, Dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:7.10
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["ghci"]
```

As [the doc mentions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

> The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent.
>   **For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile because built images should be portable**.
>   A host directory wouldn’t be available on all potential hosts.

And:

```
docker run -it -v /full/path:/app my-test bash
```

Comment: Thanks =) It works now. Why it is not possible to pass relative path in cmd? It seem to be possible with docker-compose?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Exactly: docker-compose introduced the feature of using a relative path. But that is not the case for the `docker run` command itself (which was introduced way before docker-compose itself). As mentioned here, docker-compose would translate the relative path to an absollute one anyway: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19126#issuecomment-169353931